# Casting object from erasure-type object to concrete type

Tags: c++, type-erasure

I'm trying to use Type Erasure concept. Based on the object type I'd like to cast it to concrete type. I attempted to do this as shown below, but it didn't work. It prints some number instead of 11. What am I doing wrong?

**ATTEMPT**

```
std::vector<Object> v;
v.emplace_back(Object(Obj1(11)));
v.emplace_back(Object(Obj2("test")));

Object o1 = v[0];
auto c1 = static_cast<Object::Concept*>(o1.object.get());
auto m1 = static_cast<Object::Model<Obj1>*>(c1);
std::cout << m1->object.i;
```

**CODE**

```
enum class ObjType { ObjType1, ObjType2 };
struct Object
{
   template<typename T>
   Object(T&& obj): object(std::make_shared<Model<T>>(std::forward<T>(obj))) {}

    ObjType getType() const { return object->getType(); }

    struct Concept
    {
      virtual ~Concept() {}
      virtual ObjType getType() const = 0;
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct Model : Concept
    {
        Model(const T& t) : object(t) {}
        T object;
        ObjType getType() const override { return object.getType(); }
    };

    std::shared_ptr<Concept> object;
};

struct Obj1
{
   int i;
   Obj1(int i) : i(i) {}
   ObjType getType() const { return ObjType::ObjType1; }
};

struct Obj2
{
   std::string s;
   Obj2(std::string s) : s(s) {}
   ObjType getType() const { return ObjType::ObjType2; }
};
```

Comment: It's rather curious you got anything considering it doesn't compile.

Comment: @PasserBy, I fixed it. I just copied it from my machine with some mistakes. But, I updated the post.

Comment: [It still won't compile](https://godbolt.org/z/W3K85Go1f). Please paste real code that you ran.

Comment: PasserBy, please try again. This is the real code. I fixed again and checked here https://godbolt.org/z/EMaMaGrjv

Answer (score 0):

Your templated constructor is used instead of the defaulted copy constructor you want to be used in

```
Object o1 = v[0];
```

and the constructor used here is actually `Object::Object<Object&>`.

To avoid this you could simply not make the templated constructor applicable, if the argument type is `Object` (or any reference to one):

```
struct Object
{
    template<typename T>
    requires !std::is_same_v<Object, std::remove_cvref_t<T>>
    Object(T&& obj)
        : object(std::make_shared<Model<T>>(std::forward<T>(obj)))
    {
    }
    ...
};
```

This of course could be an issue if you actually want to use an `Object::Model<Object>`; If you plan on doing that, I recommend adding a `make_object` function at namespace scope instead of implementing the object creation via constructor.

Additional note: It's quite possible that the template parameter deduced for the constructor is `Obj1&` or `Obj1 const&` (or `Obj2` equivalent), so you may want to remove the reference and possibly the `const` when choosing the type of `Model`:

```
template<typename T>
requires !std::is_same_v<Object, std::remove_cvref_t<T>>
Object(T&& obj)
    : object(std::make_shared<Model<std::remove_reference_t<T>>>(std::forward<T>(obj)))
{
}
```

or

```
template<typename T>
requires !std::is_same_v<Object, std::remove_cvref_t<T>>
Object(T&& obj)
    : object(std::make_shared<Model<std::remove_cvref_t<T>>>(std::forward<T>(obj)))
{
}
```

---

**Edit:** For C++14 concepts cannot be used and `std::remove_cvref_t` is not available either, so SFINAE and `std::remove_const_t<std::remove_reference_t<...>>` need to be used instead:

```
...
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<std::remove_const_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>, Object>::value, bool> = true>
Object(T&& obj)
    : object(std::make_shared<Model<std::remove_const_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>>>(std::forward<T>(obj)))
{
}
...
```

Comment: I get `this declaration has no storage class or type specifier` when using `requires`. I'm usin c++14.

Comment: @theateist I added a version using SFINAE to the answer; that one should be working for C++14

Comment: It worked. But, could you please explain in more details regarding **templated constructor is used instead of the defaulted copy constructo** and **simply not make the templated constructor applicable**? Why this happens. And/or provide some articles where I can read and understand this please?

Comment: @theateist not sure what articles/explanation exactly you need, depending on the argument type the templated constuctor can cover all of the signatures of copy and move constructor and more. This is why your templated constructor is used to initialize the lhs. Here's an example for a free function that should hopefully demonstrate my point https://godbolt.org/z/86Mr8jrnq . As for "not make the constructor applicable": there should be plenty of examples available when doing a web search for `SFINAE` or `std::enable_if`.

Comment: In this case we just make sure the template specialization for anything involving `Object` (`Object&&`, `Object const&`, `Object&`) fails. (We guarantee a specialization failure for these kinds of arguments making the compiler look for alternatives, which are the implicitly generated move or copy constructors.)

Comment: is there a better way to cast the inner object to the cocrete type. I mean, what can I do so I could have `v[0].as<Obj1>();` instead of casting to `Concept` and then to `Model` like I did in my post? Do I need to add `as<T>` into `Object` which will cast to `Model<T>` but internally in `Object` so I won't have to do this each type I need to cast?